# How to solve foreign key constraint violation issue when using springtestdbunit?

Tags: java, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I have two tables, one of table A's fields references table B's field, I use annotation @DatabaseSetup to do the importing of xml file, and I wrote both table A and table B's data in the dataset in the xml file. when I run the unit test, it says INSERT on table A caused a violation of foreign key constraint for key(0).

how to express the reference relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Can you provide your dataset XML file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your dataset XML file looks something along the lines of:

`<TABLE_A ID="1"/>`

`<TABLE_B ID="1" TABLE_A_ID="1"/>`

This violation could occur if:

- Your second row contains an value for the foreign key reference that doesnt exist e.g.

`<TABLE_A ID="1"/>`

`<TABLE_B ID="1" TABLE_A_ID="2"/>`

- Your dataset file inserts the rows in the wrong order e.g:

`<TABLE_B ID="1" TABLE_A_ID="1"/>`

`<TABLE_A ID="1"/>`

If you provide your dataset file and Db Unit Test I can be more specific

Comment: I think you're right, it's about the table order in the dataset definition in my xml file.